# Return a value from CommandButton1_Click() Sub in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Please note this question is related to Outlook 
I am an amateurish programmer in VB in outlook
I want to have a custom Message Box with button captions as 'Send Anyway' and 'Don't Send'.

But with the existing message box changing text is not possible.

So I made a custom form. Now I want to return a Boolean value from the  CommandButton1_Click() Sub

This is my main sub which call the form:

```
Public Result1 As Boolean
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Const MAX_ITEM_SIZE As Long = 5242880
 Result1 = True
 Dim FileSize As Long

   For Each Item In Item.Attachments
      FileSize = FileSize + Item.Size      
   Next

           If FileSize > MAX_ITEM_SIZE Then
               UserForm1.Show
               'Cancel = True
               Cancel = Result1
           End If
End Sub

This is my code for click event handler:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Unload Me
End Sub
```

Please advise on how to achieve custom captions on MsgBox Buttons in Outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the `Tag` property of the `UserForm` object to pass back a value from it to its calling sub

this means you'll want to use UserForm `Hide()` method rather then `Unload` it from within its code pane, not to loose its *state*, i.e. all its properties values (and methods calling),

So I'd go like follows:

- give meaningful names to your Userform1 button

  for instance, let's rename

  - `SendBtn`, the button that has the "Send Anyway" caption
  - `DoNotSendBtn`, the button that has the "Don't Send" caption

  you can actually use whatever name you want (even `CommandButton1` and  `CommandButton2` would do), but be consistent with chosen names for their corresponding event handlers names
- assign them the following click event handlers

  ```
  Private Sub DoNotSendBtn_Click() '<--| change "DoNotSendBtn" to your actual chosen button name
      Me.Tag = "True" '<--| store in userform 'Tag' property the value that will be read to cancel the email sending
      Me.Hide '<-- this will hide the userform, thus not loosing its "state" -> 'Tag' property will still be available to the calling sub
  End Sub

  Private Sub SendBtn_Click()'<--| change "SendBtn" to your actual chosen button name
      Me.Tag = "False" '<--| store in userform 'Tag' property the value that will be read to let the email sending go on its way
      Me.Hide '<-- this will hide the userform, thus not loosing its "state" ->  'Tag' property will still be available to the calling sub
  End Sub
  ```
- finally, change your `ItemSend` event handler like follows

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
      Const MAX_ITEM_SIZE As Long = 5242880
      Dim FileSize As Long

      For Each Item In Item.Attachments
          FileSize = FileSize + Item.Size
      Next

      If FileSize > MAX_ITEM_SIZE Then
        UserForm1.Show '<--| show the userform
        Cancel = UserForm1.Tag = "True" '<--| 'Cancel' will be set to 'True' if the userform TAG property value is "True", otherwise it'll be set to 'False'
        Unload UserForm1 '<--| now unload the Userform (and loose its "state", which you don't need any more)
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful

Comment: can you please direct me to a place where I can get study material on VB for Outlook

Comment: I haven't studied on any book for VBA Outlook. I just learned VBA for Excel and then went with Outlook online documentation, since once you grasp the VBA essentials you can use them for every Office application, provided you just get the corresponding object model. But if you google VBA for Outlook you'll certainly find as much material as you'll never be able to read in a whole life!

Comment: @karanamsairaviteja [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @user3598756 so I cannot change caption of buttons in MsgBox ??

Comment: [searching the web](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vba%20change%20msgbox%20button%20caption&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=vba%20change%20msgbox%20button%20caption&sc=0-32&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=B6311BCEDFD4473EA898B1D00F74BC94&cbust=1).  Bottom line to me is that you can but the way is build your own userform

Comment: @user3598756 Yeah even I got the same conclusion. thanks for the help